# How can I change distance between icons of the tabbar from React Navigation 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, distance, tabbar

So, here is what I currently have:

[image]

And I need distance between icons to be equal. That's what I'm unable to do using tabStyle prop like this:

```
tabStyle: {
    width: whatever
}
```

cause distance is not equal. How can I do so in React Navigation 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the labels to be as wide as the content instead of stretching to available width. In that case, you need to set `width` to `auto`:

```js
tabStyle: {
  width: 'auto'
}
```